# When is it safe to access the template id via the publishing context?

Tags: 2013-sp1, tom.net, api

In Tom.Net API for Tridion 2013 SP1 in **Engine** class for **PublishingContext** properties there is following remark:

*The **Publishing Context** consists of items in the **Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing** assembly, and serve as context for the current publishing actions. In case no **PublishingContext** is available (in practice, when a Template Building Block is being debugged in the **Template Builder**), the property-value is **null**.*

But when I use following code in c# code fragment

`string templateID = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.ResolvedItem.Template.Id.ToString();`

I am able to get both Page and Component template ID in following scenarios:

1. Publishing
2. Tridion Preview
3. Template Builder
4. XPM fast-track publishing

Is is safe to use code above in order to get **Template ID**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *mostly* safe. For `ResolvedItem` there is a note in the documentation that:

> When used through the Template Builder, the template is not set (as it need not have been saved yet)

so you may want to check the `Template` property for `null` before trying to get it's ID.

It's worth noting that you can short-cut the `RenderedItem` and go directly to the `ResolvedItem` from the `PublishingContext`and that you don't need to use `ToString()` on the `ID` property of the `Template`, so:

```
var templateID = engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Template.Id;
```

should be adequate (it'll give you a TcmUri object, but the default method of this is `ToString()` anyway).

You should also consider why you need to know the template ID. If you're using it for some conditional logic, then it's not good practice to use IDs, as they can change between environments.

#### Update:

You mention that you wish to obtain Page Template Metadata when rendering Pages... This can be achieved in a different way. You have the Page already in the package. You can get the Tridion Page object, it's Template and the Template's metadata as follows:

```
var page = (Page) engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.PageName));
var pageTemplate = page.PageTemplate;
if (pageTemplate.Metadata != null)
{
    var pageTemplateMetadata = new ItemFields(
        pageTemplate.Metadata,
        pageTemplate.MetadataSchema);
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick responce.

We're not using it for conditional logic, we need to access current **Page Template ID** in **c# code fragment** in order to read it's metadata content.
Is our approach valid or there is some better way in order to read **Page Template Metadata** while Page is rendered/previewed?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an alternative way of obtaining the page template metadata from the page object within the package passed to your template.